# TineMce edits value of data attribute on deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have 4 lines in my tinymce editor. the content looks like this:

```
"<p style="opacity: 1; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff;" data-baba="0">200&nbsp;ml&nbsp;Coca&nbsp;(24x200ml)</p>
<p style="opacity: 1; color: #ff0000; background-color: #ffffff;" data-baba="1">1&nbsp;gram&nbsp;asfsdgsdg</p>
<p style="opacity: 1; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff;" data-baba="2">100&nbsp;ml&nbsp;*!citroensap</p>
<p style="opacity: 1; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff;" data-baba="3">300&nbsp;gram&nbsp;topsikis4e</p>"
```

I place the cursor on the beggining of the third line and holding it, I select the first two lines and press delete. After that, the content of the tinymce is like this:

```
"<p style="opacity: 1; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff;" data-baba="0">100&nbsp;ml&nbsp;*!citroensap</p>
<p style="opacity: 1; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff;" data-baba="3">300&nbsp;gram&nbsp;topsikis4e</p>"
```

As you can see, the correct contents were deleted, but the parameter data-baba is wrongly deleted. That property of the first line should have the value 2, not 0 like it is now. How can I fix this, how can I stop tinymce from editing the content of data-baba?